# Click on Link in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I have some text with a link in a TextView. Now I want that the browser open the link if the user click on it. My TextView looks like this:

```
<string name="Info">Go to <a href="www.google.com">Google</a></string>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/Info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/OptionMarginBottom"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/Info" />
```

The Link is displayed correct in blue but I can not click on it. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this method

```
public static void addLink(TextView textView, String patternToMatch,
        final String link) {
    Linkify.TransformFilter filter = new Linkify.TransformFilter() {
        @Override public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
            return link;
        }
    };
    Linkify.addLinks(textView, Pattern.compile(patternToMatch), null, null,
            filter);
}
```

and use as

```
addLink(text, "^Android", "http://abhiandroidinfo.blogspot.in");
```

Comment: Works good thank you! But I have to remove `LinksClickable` and `AutoLink` from the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Linkify` on your `TextView`

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourTextviewObject, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

> Linkify take a piece of text and a regular expression and turns all of
>   the regex matches in the text into clickable links.

Comment: the textview contains a website ? Something like http://www.google.com? . If you want the html approach you have so set  text inside your textview at runtime with yourTextviewObject.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.info)));

Comment: The TextView contains the string from above with text and a link `Go to <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>`

Comment: then at runtime yourTextviewObject.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.info))); and it should works

Comment: No sorry does not work... In the onCreateView of my Fragment I call `TextView tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Info); tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Icon))); Linkify.addLinks(tv, Linkify.WEB_URLS);` Do I have to set special values on my TextView?

Comment: why R.string.Icon ? the String is R.string.Info. You can rid of Linkify in this case

Answer (score 0):

Helper Method:

```
public static void addLinks(TextView textView, String linkThis, String toThis) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(linkThis);
        String scheme = toThis;
        android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, scheme, new MatchFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean acceptMatch(CharSequence s, int start, int end) {
                return true;
            }
        }, new TransformFilter() {

            @Override
            public String transformUrl(Matcher match, String url) {
                return "";
            }
        });
    }
```

Now use like Below:

```
String weblink = "WebsiteName";
String url = course.getString(TAG_Info);

TextView txtInfo= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Info);
txtInfo.setText(userCanSeeThis);

addLinks(txtInfo, weblink, url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier method is to make a string and add Link Text
and in the xml file, make the textView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:text="@string/string_with_link" />
```